# SSIS FTP task connection error

Tags: ssis

I have a FTP connection manager in SSIS.

I have configured it with serevr IP, port number, user name, and password.
It was working fine.

But suddenly its stopped working.
But i am able to login directly to the FTP web site directly .It was not working temporarily.But now its working with same login credentials.

But my FTP connection manager in SSIS is unable to connect to the server.

with following Error message
"connection cannot be established.server name ,port number ,credentials may be invalid"

What could be the reason?

I have checked servername,port and login credentials all are same.

Note: This is a ssl ftp website(https://xxx.xx.xx.com/)

Some one please look into this isssue and provide a solution.

Thanks

SNA

Answer (score 0):

Few things on my mind, Does Machine with SQL server and SSIS have internet access, Sometimes passive and active mod on ftp connection causes errors,

Also try ask on [SF](https://serverfault.com/) sister site, probably there is lot more guys that can help You.

Comment: Yes the machine has internet access.And i am able to login FTP serevr from the browser. But it fails through SSIS.

and i hav tried both active and passive modes and URL and IP address of server also.